# What does `<no location info>: error: module ‘Module.Path’ is a package module` mean when using `stack ghci`?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci, haskell-stack

What may be the reason behind the following kind of errors?

```
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/user/.ghci

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘Settings.StaticFiles’ is a package module

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘Import.NoFoundation’ is a package module

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘Handler.Home’ is a package module
```

I've been reorganizing my `.cabal` file (`package.yaml`, really) when it started showing up when trying to invoke `stack ghci`.

And what can be done to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually quite unsure what it means and what might cause them but I've found a fix that has worked for me so far.

I've had a `hs-source-dirs` entry of `./.`, which I've changed to be `.`. And put it at the end of the list too. Not sure of the significance of this, but maybe others find it helpful when they stumble into this while googling for the error. (My searches turned up nothing related.)